# SilverStripe CMS custom css

Tags: silverstripe

When you set an extra **css class** to a CMSField by `->addExtraClass("my-class");`, which css file can you edit to set the styling for this new css class?

The only way I see now is by editing either css files in the Framework or CMS folder, something I rather avoid doing.

Is it possible to include a link to a custom css stylesheet in the CMS area where I can place all the css code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load your custom Stylesheet into the CMS by adding the following to your `config.yml` file:

```
LeftAndMain:
  extra_requirements_css:
    - mysite/css/mystyle.css
```

Comment: Rather unexpected location to include css, but it works!

Comment: As of 4.3, you will need the full namespace in your `config.yml` file.
`SilverStripe\Admin\LeftAndMain:`

Answer (score 2):

you can add code like this...

```
    Requirements::customCSS('
        #Form_FilterForm .field {
            display:inline-block;
            width:31%
        }
    ');
```

...almost anywhere and it will be included.

If these must be in the head tag then...

```
    Requirements::insertHeadTags("
        <style>
            #Form_FilterForm .field {
                display:inline-block;
                width:31%
            }
        </style>
    ");
```

Comment: That looks convenient, but I'm looking for a way to inject a css file into the CMS <head> area thus keeping CSS and PHP seperated

Comment: ok, I've updated it so you could add them in head if you wish :)

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work indeed but it's not including an external css file, which I'm striving to accomplish.

Comment: ok, well the insert head tags would have done the same as the insert head tags... but as it's an external file... well it's another way to do it :)